# What's mounting my systemd automount?

Tags: mount, fstab, systemd, automount

I've set up a systemd automount for an sshfs in /etc/fstab approximately as follows:

```
me@server:  /mount/point  fuse.sshfs  noauto,_netdev,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=900,default_permissions,allow_other,uid=josh,gid=josh,transform_symlinks  0  0
```

This works great, except that sometimes I'll notice that it's mounted even though I've not accessed it recently. Looking in journalctl, apparently there's a process called `pool` that's causing systemd to mount it every so often:

```
$ journalctl -u mount-point.automount -n10
Mar 04 22:17:39 hostname systemd[1]: mount-point.automount: Got automount request for /mount/point, triggered by 11546 (pool)
Mar 04 22:53:03 hostname systemd[1]: mount-point.automount: Got automount request for /mount/point, triggered by 27856 (pool)
Mar 05 00:31:36 hostname systemd[1]: mount-point.automount: Got automount request for /mount/point, triggered by 9083 (pool)
Mar 05 01:44:21 hostname systemd[1]: mount-point.automount: Got automount request for /mount/point, triggered by 32232 (pool)
Mar 05 17:32:31 hostname systemd[1]: mount-point.automount: Got automount request for /mount/point, triggered by 10771 (pool)
Mar 05 17:59:01 hostname systemd[1]: mount-point.automount: Got automount request for /mount/point, triggered by 18662 (pool)
Mar 05 20:05:10 hostname systemd[1]: mount-point.automount: Got automount request for /mount/point, triggered by 3259 (pool)
Mar 05 20:36:21 hostname systemd[1]: mount-point.automount: Got automount request for /mount/point, triggered by 16858 (pool)
Mar 05 22:29:33 hostname systemd[1]: mount-point.automount: Got automount request for /mount/point, triggered by 20812 (pool)
Mar 05 23:39:16 hostname systemd[1]: mount-point.automount: Got automount request for /mount/point, triggered by 15976 (pool)
```

I've looked for binaries called `pool` on my system, but I can't find any, and there doesn't appear to be any process called `pool` running at the moment. I'd rather not hang around watching journalctl until something appears to try and find out what this is, though I guess I'll do that if I have to.

What's making systemd mount my automount?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your automount is located under `/media`.

I had the same problem, *very* short-lived processes were triggering my automount every few minutes. Capturing any info about them was remarkably challenging.

For the record, what I did was:

- First, launch a shell with `stdbuf -i0 -oL -eL bash` 
  (This launches a shell with buffering of pipes adjusted to send every line right away, instead of the default which will buffer a bunch of output before it actually sends anything.)
- In that shell, run this hideous command-line, which I really should have formatted into a proper script in a .sh file but didn't: \

```
journalctl --unit UNITNAME.automount -f | grep -oP '(?<=^|[^0-9])[0-9]{4,}(?=[^0-9]|$)' | while read pid; do if [ -e /proc/"$pid"/status ] ; then if [ -e proc-capture/"$pid" ] ; then echo "Already captured PID $pid. Ignoring"; else echo "Capturing $pid."; mkdir proc-capture/"$pid"; cp /proc/"$pid"/status proc-capture/"$pid"; fi; else echo "No current status for PID $pid. Skipping"; fi; done
```

(Adjusting the unit names as needed and the output directory if you like.)

- Wait.

Note: You may need root for this. I always add my own regular user account to group `adm`, which gives read access to system log stuff including `journalctl` (on Debian, but I would guess that's the same on Ubuntu), so I didn't need sudo or anything for the script to work.

Then, whenever the polling process fires up and does its thing, the script will copy its `/proc/<PID>/status` into `proc-capture/<PID>/` (under your current working directory) immediately, before the process ends and that status file ceases to exist. That file will tell you the PPID, that is, the PID of the *parent* of the PID in question. In my case, the parent was systemd, doing whatever behind-the-scenes magic is involved in automatically mounting USB drives under `/media` the moment they're plugged in and such. It may be possible to configure that subsystem to ignore specified directories under `/media`, but in my case just moving the automount from `/media` to `/mnt` made the problem go away so I didn't dig any deeper.